# State cannot be read when using State Processor Api

Tags: apache-flink

A Flink Streaming was developed with a filter that does the deduplication based on the id of the event using a key-value state based on RocksDB state backend.

**Application Code**

```
env.setStateBackend(new RocksDBStateBackend(checkpoint, true).asInstanceOf[StateBackend])

val stream = env
  .addSource(kafkaConsumer)
  .keyBy(_.id)
  .filter(new Deduplication[Stream]("stream-dedup", Time.days(30))).uid("stream-filter")
```

**Deduplication Code**

```
class Deduplication[T](stateDescriptor: String, time: Time) extends RichFilterFunction[T] {
  val ttlConfig: StateTtlConfig = StateTtlConfig
    .newBuilder(time)
    .setUpdateType(StateTtlConfig.UpdateType.OnReadAndWrite)
    .setStateVisibility(StateTtlConfig.StateVisibility.NeverReturnExpired)
    .cleanupFullSnapshot
    .build

  val deduplicationStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor[Boolean](stateDescriptor, classOf[Boolean])
  deduplicationStateDescriptor.enableTimeToLive(ttlConfig)
  lazy val deduplicationState: ValueState[Boolean] = getRuntimeContext.getState(deduplicationStateDescriptor)

  override def filter(value: T): Boolean = {
    if (deduplicationState.value) {
      false
    } else {
      deduplicationState.update(true)
      true
    }
  }
}
```

All of this works just fine. My goal with this question is to understand how I can read all the state using [state processor api](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/libs/state_processor_api.html). So I started to write some code based on the documentation available.

**Savepoint Reading Code**

```
val env: ExecutionEnvironment = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

val savepoint = Savepoint
    .load(env, savepointPath,new RocksDBStateBackend("file:/tmp/rocksdb", true))

savepoint
    .readKeyedState("stream-filter", new DeduplicationStateReader("stream-dedup")).print()
```

**Reader Function Code**

```
class DeduplicationStateReader(stateDescriptor: String) extends KeyedStateReaderFunction[String, String] {
  var state: ValueState[Boolean] = _

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    val deduplicationStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor[Boolean](stateDescriptor, classOf[Boolean])
    state = getRuntimeContext.getState(deduplicationStateDescriptor)
  }

  override def readKey(key: String, ctx: KeyedStateReaderFunction.Context, out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
    out.collect("IT IS WORKING")
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to read the state, a serialization error appears to me.

[image]

Is there anything wrong? Did I misunderstand all of this?

Comment: Some additional information: The state just keeps a boolean indicating that the key has already passed through the streaming. If you guys see the KeyedStateReaderFunction, I return a string just for debug.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong. There's a working example here -- https://github.com/ververica/flink-training/blob/master/state-processor/src/main/java/com/ververica/flink/training/exercises/ReadRidesAndFaresSnapshot.java -- if you want to compare.

Comment: I'll take a look at it.